# Why does the text printed after my variable appear on a new line?

Tags: ruby

```
puts "Hey what's your name?!!"
name = gets
puts "#outputNAME: #{name}"
puts "Hey #{name}! Howdy doin'!"
puts "Tell us 2 numbers that add up to your age!"
age1 = gets.to_i
age2 = gets.to_i
puts "Hey! You're #{age1 + age2} years old! Gotcha!"
puts "I'm totally new to Ruby on Rails, so thanks for running my first Ruby 
Program. Please do leave an upvote and I'll appreciate that."
puts "If you think I need a downvote, please do state, in the comments 
section, what I could have done to make my program better (my 1st program, 
remember that #{name}). Also, check out my HTML pages, as I'm an ace at 
HTML."

print "Thanks, once again #{name} and stay tuned (especially for my HTML 
projects)!"
```

In this part, after `#{name}`, the sentence is continued on a new line, which I want not to happen. Is there any explanation as to what could be the error in my program, or is it an error in the language? Please help me, as I'm doing an individual project.
Thanks to whoever does find the solution to this problem.

Comment: _"is it an error in the language"_ - Welcome to Stack Overflow and to your journey as a programmer. One thing to keep in mind as you learn is that this is pretty much, almost **never** the explanation :)

Comment: FYI `puts` accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: It's extremely important to be civil and respectful on Stack Overflow. Telling people off for giving you advice is not constructive. When it comes to programming, be humble. 99.9999% of the time the error is in *your* code and not the programming language. In that 0.0001% situation where it's not your code and it is in the language the usual procedure is to make a minimal test case that proves the flaw, then file a bug report.

Comment: Got it, @tadman. I apologize, mikej. ☺

Answer (score 3):

it prints text to the new line after `name`, because you are accepting newline character in the following code.

`name = gets`

```
name = gets
raj
 => "raj\n"
```

you can remove such newline character by `chomp` method.

```
name = gets.chomp
raj
 => "raj"
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! This helped me. ☺

Comment: just go through some basics of ruby language, https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/

Comment: Thanks to all of ya. But, please stop posting comments(no offence), cuz it's flooding my Inbox(Gmail).